# Javascript make HTTP request on regular interval not working

Tags: javascript

I have a page  to show the chat messages.  I need to refresh the chat body every 30 seconds to load the new messages. I have  set the interval to 30 seconds , the function is running , but its not making the HTTP request. Here is my code

```
function loadmessages(){

   var ids = document.getElementById("pid").value;
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("get", '/refresh_message/'+ ids );
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content);
  request.onload = function(){
  if(this.status == 200){
    var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(resp.message);

    }
    else{
        console.log(this.status);
    }

request.send(null); 
}


}

loadmessages(); 
setInterval(function(){
    loadmessages() 
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent indentation matters. You're putting `request.send(null);` inside the `request.onload` function, so of course it never gets sent in the first place. Try putting it outside, instead:

```
function loadmessages() {
  var ids = document.getElementById("pid").value;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("get", '/refresh_message/' + ids);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(resp.message);
    } else {
      console.log(this.status);
    }
  }
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, my bad . Thank you.

Comment: I was just about to type this out and notice the 1 new answer pop up on the screen. :)

I would suggest, just to future proof your code, that you also set a handler on your setInterval in case later on you need to stop it or otherwise interrupt the process.  Just a sort of best practice, so not worth an answer in an of itself.

Comment: @Carnix Yes I should have thought of that, thank you for the suggestion.